# SwiftUI: Building a list of navigation links using ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I build a list of navigation list using ForEach in SwiftUI.
I thought of something like below but it doesn't work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  var menuButtons = ["Profile", "About Us", "Contact Us"]
  
    var body: some View {
        
      ForEach(menuButtons, id:\.self) {menu in
        NavigationView(content: {
          NavigationLink(destination: {
            if menu == "Profile" {
              Profile()
            }
            if menu == "About Us" {
              AboutUs()
            }
          }) { Text(menu) }
        })
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move the `NavigationView` outside the `ForEach`, otherwise you'll have multiple navigation views.
2. You also want a `VStack` that wraps the `ForEach`, so the navigation links are stacked.
3. Wrap the `if` statements inside a `Group` to group it into a single View, which the `destination` expects.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var menuButtons = ["Profile", "About Us", "Contact Us"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { /// 1.
            VStack { /// 2.
                ForEach(menuButtons, id: \.self) { menu in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination:
                            Group { /// 3.
                                if menu == "Profile" {
                                    Profile()
                                }
                                if menu == "About Us" {
                                    AboutUs()
                                }
                            }
                    ) {
                        Text(menu)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

| Home page (ContentView) | After clicking a navigation link |
| --- | --- |
| [image: "Profile", "About Us", and "Contact Us" stacked vertically] | [image: Profile view displayed with back button to go back] |

Comment: In the front page, how can the list be shown so  user can select to go profile or about us...

Comment: @DarylWong I added an image, is that what you want?